# Query of duplicate rows in temp table results in rows which are not duplicates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

To reproduce, I build the following temp table and populate it with data:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempActualsImport 
(
        AID                 INT                 NULL,
        PostedDate          NVARCHAR(255)       NULL,
        AccountingPeriod    NVARCHAR(255)       NULL,
        JournalDate         NVARCHAR(255)       NULL,
        JournalID           NVARCHAR(255)       NULL,
        JournalDescription  NVARCHAR(1000)      NULL,
        JournalLine         INT                 NULL, 
        PaymentAmt          NVARCHAR(255)       NULL,
        RelativeAmount      NUMERIC(32,2)       NULL,
        IRSDuplicateRows    BIT                 DEFAULT 0 NULL, 
        Recstamp            Timestamp
)
```

The following query updates the temp table based on the following criteria to find duplicates called IRS duplicates.

```
UPDATE #TempActualsImport 
SET IRSDuplicateRows = 1
WHERE AID IN (SELECT t1.AID 
              FROM #TempActualsImport t1, #TempActualsImport t2 
              WHERE t1.PostedDate = t2.PostedDate
                AND t1.AccountingPeriod = t2.AccountingPeriod
                AND t1.JournalDate = t2.JournalDate
                AND t1.JournalID = t2.JournalID
                AND t1.JournalDescription = t2.JournalDescription
                AND t1.JournalLine = t2.JournalLine
                AND t1.PaymentAmt = t2.PaymentAmt
                AND t1.RelativeAmount = t2.RelativeAmount
                AND CONVERT(DATE, t1.PostedDate) = '2018-10-03'   
                AND t1.RelativeAmount = 0
                AND t1.AID = t2.AID)
```

The following query is run against the temp table:

```
SELECT
    AID, PostedDate, AccountingPeriod, 
    JournalDate, JournalID, JournalDescription, JournalLine, PaymentAmt, 
    RelativeAmount, IRSDuplicateRows
FROM
    #TempActualsImport 
WHERE
    IRSDuplicateRows = 1
```

The following two rows are marked as duplicates, but clearly the JournalLine (7th column in) does NOT match for these two records.

```
589 20181003    4   20181002    PR00154645  10/02/2018 Payroll  8399         
0.00    1

808 20181003    4   20181002    PR00154645  10/02/2018 Payroll  15888        
0.00    1
```

I would expect these two records to not show up as an IRS duplicate because the JournalLine column does not match.  What am I doing wrong?

I have tested this on SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2016 with the same results.

Here is some sample data to populate #TempActualsImport:

```
INSERT [#TempActualsImport] ([AID], [POSTEDDate], [AccountingPeriod], 
[JournalDate], [JournalID], [JournalDescription], [JournalLine], 
[PaymentAmt], [RelativeAmount]) VALUES (589, N'20181003', N'4', N'20181002', 
N'PR00154645', N'10/02/2018 Payroll', 8399, N'', CAST(0.00 AS Numeric(32, 
2)))
GO

INSERT [#TempActualsImport] ([AID], [POSTEDDate], [AccountingPeriod], 
[JournalDate], [JournalID], [JournalDescription], [JournalLine], 
[PaymentAmt], [RelativeAmount]) VALUES (711, N'20181003', N'4', N'20181002', 
N'PR00154645', N'10/02/2018 Payroll', 12486, N'', CAST(1846.96 AS 
Numeric(32, 2)))
GO

 INSERT [#TempActualsImport] ([AID], [POSTEDDate], [AccountingPeriod], 
 [JournalDate], [JournalID], [JournalDescription], [JournalLine], 
 [PaymentAmt], [RelativeAmount]) VALUES (712, N'20181003', N'4', 
 N'20181002', N'PR00154645', N'10/02/2018 Payroll', 12487, N'', CAST(169.33 
 AS Numeric(32, 2)))
 GO

INSERT [#TempActualsImport] ([AID], [POSTEDDate], [AccountingPeriod], 
[JournalDate], [JournalID], [JournalDescription], [JournalLine], 
[PaymentAmt], [RelativeAmount]) VALUES (713, N'20181003', N'4', N'20181002', 
N'PR00154645', N'10/02/2018 Payroll', 12488, N'', CAST(205.46 AS Numeric(32, 
2)))
GO

INSERT [#TempActualsImport] ([AID], [POSTEDDate], [AccountingPeriod], 
[JournalDate], [JournalID], [JournalDescription], [JournalLine], 
[PaymentAmt], [RelativeAmount]) VALUES (714, N'20181003', N'4', N'20181002', 
N'PR00154645', N'10/02/2018 Payroll', 12489, N'', CAST(121.95 AS Numeric(32, 
2)))
GO

INSERT [#TempActualsImport] ([AID], [POSTEDDate], [AccountingPeriod], 
[JournalDate], [JournalID], [JournalDescription], [JournalLine], 
[PaymentAmt], [RelativeAmount]) VALUES (715, N'20181003', N'4', N'20181002', 
N'PR00154645', N'10/02/2018 Payroll', 12490, N'', CAST(19.48 AS Numeric(32, 
2)))
GO

INSERT [#TempActualsImport] ([AID], [POSTEDDate], [AccountingPeriod], 
[JournalDate], [JournalID], [JournalDescription], [JournalLine], 
[PaymentAmt], [RelativeAmount]) VALUES (716, N'20181003', N'4', N'20181002', 
N'PR00154645', N'10/02/2018 Payroll', 12663, N'', CAST(1538.85 AS 
Numeric(32, 2)))
GO

INSERT [#TempActualsImport] ([AID], [POSTEDDate], [AccountingPeriod], 
[JournalDate], [JournalID], [JournalDescription], [JournalLine], 
[PaymentAmt], [RelativeAmount]) VALUES (717, N'20181003', N'4', N'20181002', 
N'PR00154645', N'10/02/2018 Payroll', 12664, N'', CAST(13.57 AS Numeric(32, 
2)))
GO

INSERT [#TempActualsImport] ([AID], [POSTEDDate], [AccountingPeriod], 
[JournalDate], [JournalID], [JournalDescription], [JournalLine], 
[PaymentAmt], [RelativeAmount]) VALUES (808, N'20181003', N'4', N'20181002', 
N'PR00154645', N'10/02/2018 Payroll', 15888, N'', CAST(0.00 AS Numeric(32, 
2)))
GO
```

Comment: should this be `<>` instead of `=` in the query check, Ex: `t1.AID <> t2.AID`, do duplicate rows have same AID? The query you have is self joining and returning same row for update. I don't see any restrictions or condition to identify actual duplicates here

Comment: I can leave out the final criteria in the WHERE clause - AND t1.AID = t2.AID - and this still results in these two rows found as duplicates, so this being = or <> makes no difference.

Comment: Your query to identify them as duplicate is wrong, any row with posted date 2018-10-03 and 0 amount will be returned in the subquery even when there is no duplicate or when there is only single row and update them as duplicate

Comment: So any suggestion on how to find these duplicates rs?

Comment: post sample data with and without duplicates and expected output, you will need to define what is considered duplicate row here. Above query doesn't help because it is just taking all the rows joining to itself and updating flag.

Comment: The query eliminates every duplicate except the two rows I posted.

Comment: @StevenJe I don't believe you.   Please post a script that populates the table with data that reproduces the issue.   The most likely answer is that you are misinterpreting what you are seeing.  I would expect your posted UPDATE to flag every row as a duplicate.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: @RS, why would I post this if I was lying and not seeing this?  I can't post data from our production systems out there, so that is not going to happen. And yes, I could be misinterpreting the results or seeing this incorrectly, but I can't post production data. I have been trying to figure this out for three days now.

Comment: You don't need to post production data. We just need a data set that reproduces your issue. It can be modified data from your system, or entirely made up, so long as it presents the same error you're experiencing. See [why it matters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) then [Start Here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for tips.

Comment: Edited to add sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finished testing, the following was able to resolve the problem and find the duplicates I am checking for by using a common table expression. (note: had to add the ; before WITH for this to compile in a stored procedure)

```
;WITH CTE AS
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PostedDate, AccountingPeriod, JournalDate, 
JournalID,  JournalLine,JournalDescription,
    PaymentAmt, RelativeAmount
ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS DuplicateRowNumber
    FROM #TempActualsImport
    WHERE CONVERT(DATE,PostedDate)  = '2018-10-03' 
    AND PaymentAmt = 0
)
Update CTE SET IRSDuplicateRows = 1 
where DuplicateRowNumber > 1
```

Comment: This did resolve the problem and was incorporated into the larger ETL stored procedure.  I had to add  as semicolon like ;WITH to get this work, but it compiles fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now that I have run the query myself with the sample code you provided, I can explain why you saw the behavior you saw.

As I posted in my comment, I would expect the update you used to mark every row as a duplicate.  The reason being that when you join a table to itself, every row will have a matching row on the other side of the join, because every row will match itself.

However, in your case the only two rows that matched and were marked as duplicates were the rows with "0.00" in the `RelativeAmount` column.   And the reason for that is this line in the UPDATE which I didn't notice before:

```
AND t1.RelativeAmount = 0
```

Comment out that line, and ALL the rows in your table (with 10/3 as the posted date) will get flagged as duplicates.

Comment: Thanks @Tab Alleman for taking the time, but one of the duplicate criteria is that RelativeAmount = 0 so this can't be removed.  I have it working with the CTE code I posted yesterday and this finds the actual duplicates. Thanks again!

Comment: @StevenJe I know, this answer wasn't meant to suggest that you should remove the `relativeAmount=0` condition; it was just meant to explain the reason why you got the result you did from your original code.   If you have already solved the problem, there is no need to suggest additional solutions.